# jquery keyup event wont trigger add/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a regular input field that is used to filter a DataTable. I have a keyup function on the input that triggers `fnFilter`, i would also like to change the color of the input to notify the user that the filter is active.

This is my code:

css

```
.pn-input {
        border-color:#4d4f53;
}

.pn-input-active {
        border-color:#126C00;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#searchfield').keyup(function () {
    oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());

    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('pn-input');
        $(this).addClass('pn-input-active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('pn-input-active');
        $(this).addClass('pn-input');
    }
});
```

The `fnFilter` triggers correct for each character, but the input does not. The color only changes when i click outside of the text input.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7o03dfpe/1/

Comment: That's wierd, it doesn't work on my project...

Comment: Have you made sure that you load jQuery correctly? Any other code overriding any `input` elements? etc etc.

Comment: try to call the fnFilter after your if-else block. may be it is returning something

Comment: I took a closer look in my bootstrap.css and i can't find any code that would override the input.

Comment: show your fnFilter function, put a console.log inside the if and the else tree and check if it's even goin inside those conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change css into

```
.pn-input {
  border-color:#4d4f53!important;
}

.pn-input.pn-input-active {
  border-color:#126C00!important;
}
```

script into

```
$('#searchfield').keyup(function () {
    var Self=$(this);
    oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());

    if ($(Self).val().length > 0) {
      $(Self).addClass('pn-input-active');
    } else {
      $(Self).removeClass('pn-input-active');
    }
});
```